# Cannot add Ktor Client to Spring Boot Maven project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, kotlin, intellij-idea, ktor-client

So I'm trying to add Ktor Client to my Spring Boot Maven project but IntelliJ does not detect the dependencies. Already tried with reimporting maven dependencies, cleaning cache, mvn idea:idea and also creating another Spring Boot Maven project in a different machine and still doesn't work.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoproject</name>
    <description>demoproject</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.6.10</kotlin.version>
        <ktor.version>1.6.7</ktor.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-kotlin-extensions</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-reactor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-client-cio</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-client-serialization</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And this is what I get in IntelliJ:

[image: IntelliJ Result]

Comment: do you have `ERROR - on.CompletionProgressIndicator - Can't find built-in class kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction0 
` error in the idea.log?

Comment: Seems similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-20948. Try the suggestions from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-20948#focus=Comments-27-5733617.0-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the jvm suffix because it is a multiplatform library and determining appropriate artifacts based on a platform isn’t supported for Maven.

Here’s an example: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.ktor/ktor-client-core-jvm/1.6.7